# Join 2 tables by 1 field, partial matching on other two fields - no cartesian product

Tags: sql, oracle, join, similarity

I have 2 tables, representing the substitutions of components in an intervention (ID_TK), each with a Part Number OLD and a Part Number NEW, from two different systems point of view (PN OLD and NEW in one system, HWC OLD and NEW in the other one).

The number of rows in the two tables may be different for each ID_TK.

ID_SOST is the unique KEY in the first table, PR_ID is the unique key in the second one.

However, only the id intervention (ID_TK) links the two tables exactly.
I have to check if the substitutions match in the two tables for each intervention. 
"Match" means: same ID_TK, AND PN_OLD must be substring (or equal) to HWC_OLD, AND PN_NEW must be substring (or equal) to HWC_NEW (both uppercase):

```
case 
  when 
   (UPPER(PN_NEW) = UPPER(SUBSTR(HWC_NEW,1,LENGTH(PN_NEW))) AND UPPER(PN_OLD) = UPPER(SUBSTR(HWC_OLD,1,LENGTH(PN_OLD)))) THEN 'YES' else 'NO' as MATCH
```

[image]

In the desiderata result table, the "matching" couples ID_SOST-PR_ID have to be listed first, and they have not been considered for any other matching in the ID_TK (the best option is the exact match); the remaining non-matching couples have to be listed after the matching ones, first listing the better similarity. The difficulty is that I don't want to show the cartesian product of the non-matching substitutions(PRs and ID_SOSTs). BTW, if the number of PR (or SOST) is different, null will fill the missing fields.

Comment: Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the question tags and include the DDL for the table(s) involved and data for each of the tables **as formatted text, in the question itself**. Images of code or data is not particularly useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So first, for future reference, here's how to give example data in a question:

```
create table table1 (id_tk varchar2(20), id_sost varchar2(20), hwc_old varchar2(20), hwc_new varchar2(20));
create table table2 (id_tk varchar2(20), pr_id varchar2(20), pn_old varchar2(20), pn_new varchar2(20));

insert into table1 values ('TK0000001296676', '00000000199412', '3AL80407AA', '3AL80407AA');
insert into table1 values ('TK0000001296676', '00000000199413', '3AL79090BAAS', '3AL79090BAAS');

insert into table2 values ('TK0000001296676', 'pr-20191025-008', '3AL79090BAAS04', '3AL79090BA');
insert into table2 values ('TK0000001296676', 'pr-20191115-009', '3AL79090BA', '3AL79090BA');
insert into table2 values ('TK0000001296676', 'pr-20191115-011', '3AL79090BAAS04', '3AL79090BA');
```

It's very helpful - please don't make us re-type text that you already have. Just copy/pasting the data from Excel is fine too.

For the actual query - we're doing a full outer join, and only including the rows which either match, or have nulls instead of a match. We could also have written this as a full outer join, excluding the cartesian product rows which don't match.

```
select nvl(table1.id_tk, table2.id_tk) as id_tk, id_sost, hwc_old, hwc_new, pr_id, pn_old, pn_new,
    case when (UPPER(PN_NEW) = UPPER(SUBSTR(HWC_NEW,1,LENGTH(PN_NEW))) AND UPPER(PN_OLD) = UPPER(SUBSTR(HWC_OLD,1,LENGTH(PN_OLD)))) THEN 'YES' else 'NO' end as MATCH
from table1
full outer join table2
    on (table1.id_tk = table2.id_tk -- display matches if they exist
    and UPPER(PN_NEW) = UPPER(SUBSTR(HWC_NEW,1,LENGTH(PN_NEW))) 
    and UPPER(PN_OLD) = UPPER(SUBSTR(HWC_OLD,1,LENGTH(PN_OLD)))
    ) OR ( -- also include rows with no matches
        (id_sost is null or pr_id is null))
order by MATCH desc -- show matches first
;
```

Output - my output is a little different from yours, because I don't think you really want to have non-matching `ID_SOST - PR_ID` data in the same row. It's hard to do in SQL, and I think this way is more clear that the table1/table2 data in the row is not a match with each other.

```
ID_TK           ID_SOST HWC_OLD         HWC_NEW         PR_ID           PN_OLD          PN_NEW      MATCH
TK0000001296676 199413  3AL79090BAAS    3AL79090BAAS    pr-20191115-009 3AL79090BA      3AL79090BA  YES
TK0000001296676 null    null            null            pr-20191115-011 3AL79090BAAS04  3AL79090BA  NO
TK0000001296676 null    null            null            pr-20191025-008 3AL79090BAAS04  3AL79090BA  NO
TK0000001296676 199412  3AL80407AA      3AL80407AA      null            null            null        NO
```

Comment: Hi kfinity, thank you for your quick and kind reply; I'll take your advice about posting my future questions; Your query didn't work for me, there's a little typo in the data you've entered: insert into table1 values ('TK0000001296676', '00000000199412' --> is '00000000199413' .   If I run your query I get only two rows, I can't understand why:  ID_TK ID_SOST   HWC_OLD HWC_NEW PR_ID PN_OLD PN_NEW MATCH
TK0000001296676, 199413, 3AL79090BAAS, 3AL79090BAAS, pr-20191115-009, 3AL79090BA, 3AL79090BA, YES
TK0000001296676, 199412, 3AL80407AA, 3AL80407AA, null, null,  NO

Comment: Thanks @Juliet, I edited to fix the typo. I'm not sure why you're only getting 2 rows... maybe your data is different somehow? Here's a dbfiddle so you can play with the results: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e4dfde093f766f90d1935b200c81a272